# I'm Trying to sort pandas aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to aggregate and sort data from my dataset, but I don't know how to do. Can someone help me?

```
data = {'message_id':  ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2'],
        'to': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'five'],
        'idt': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','5']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['message_id','to','idt'])

agg_func_text = {'to': [ set], 'idt': [ set]}

df.sort_values(by=['message_id', 'to'])

df3=df.groupby(['message_id']).agg(agg_func_text)
```

as result:

```
message_id  to set              idt set
1       {four, three, one, two}     {2, 3, 1, 4}
2       {five, six}         {5, 6}
```

but I would like to recevied this as result:

```
message_id  to set              idt set
1       {one, two, three, four}     {1, 2, 3, 4}
2       {five, six}         {5, 6}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `python set` is not defined order, so cannot sorting or change ordering there, possible soution is use `dict.fromkeys().keys()` trick for remove duplicates and output is `tuple` (which should be sorted and there is also defined order):

```
f = lambda x: dict.fromkeys(x).keys()
agg_func_text = {'to': f, 'idt': f}

#if need sorting assign back
df = df.sort_values(by=['message_id', 'idt'])

df3=df.groupby('message_id').agg(agg_func_text)

print (df3)
                                 to           idt
message_id                                       
1           (one, two, three, four)  (1, 2, 3, 4)
2                       (five, six)        (5, 6)
```

Comment: why dict.fromkeys(x).keys()  sort the character representation of the numbers?  can your provide the values for dict

Answer (score 0):

sort using a number in a dictionary, save the results, then translate from the number back to a character representation of the number.

```
 data = {'message_id':  ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2'],
    'to': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'five'],
    'idt': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','5']
    }

 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['message_id','to','idt'])
 print(df)
 agg_func_text = {'to': set, 'idt': set}
 df.sort_values(by=['message_id', 'to'])

 grouped=df.groupby(['message_id']).agg(agg_func_text)

 grouped['idt']=grouped['idt'].apply(lambda x: sorted(x))
 dct={'one':1, 'two':2,'three':3,'four':4,'five':5,'six':6,'seven':7,'eight':8,'nine':9}
 dct2={1: 'one',2:'two',3:'three',4:'four',5:'five',6:'six',7:'seven',8:'eight',9:'nine'}
 grouped['to']=grouped['to'].apply(lambda x: sorted([dct[item] for item in x]))
 grouped['to']=grouped['to'].apply(lambda x: [dct2[item] for item in x])
 print(grouped)

 output:
                          to           idt
 message_id                                       
 1           [one, two, three, four]  [1, 2, 3, 4]
 2                       [five, six]        [5, 6]
```